# Maintaining the scale of an element on different window sizes

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I am trying to maintain an element in perfect scale on responsive design.
So the width should be 100% and the height should be 56% of the width.

However, if the dimensions of the window change, and the height of the window is reduced, the width should be reduced proportionally, to keep it in scale.

Likewise if the width of the window is made more narrow, then we would want the width to adjust as well, proportionally.

The width of the element is based on the width of the window.

```
<div id="intro_cont">

<div id="video_cont">
    <div id="text_cont">
        <p id="intro_text" class="intro_text">Looking For Reliable, Accurate Measurement Equipment?</p>
        <p id="intro_text2" class="intro_text">We Can Help You</p>
        <div id="play_cont">
            <div id="play_button"></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
    <div id="intro_video">
        <iframe id="video_iframe" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/#t=0s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    dimension = 0.56;
    cont_width = $('#video_cont').width();
    cont_height = $('#video_cont').height();
    video_width = cont_width;
    video_height = video_width * dimension;
    if(video_height < video_width * dimension) {
        video_height = video_width * dimension;
    }

    $('#video_iframe').css({'width':video_width,'height':video_height});
});
```

This code works for when you adjust the width, but when the height changes, the element doesnt scale.

Comment: have you just played around with css? `min-width` and max-width`? those will scale divs in both directions, typically.

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess, but you may only be constraining the video_height while width is still an independent parameter. Try adding this code block to use together with the other if statement:

```
if(video_width > video_height / dimension) {
    video_width = video_height / dimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code, you have set the height of the frame base on the width of the screen.
You need to check the window height change while the screen width is fixed.

Here is my sample code to check the window height change and resize the video frame.
You can check it but i think this is not exactly what you want. But you can have a look on it first.

```
if(video_height < video_width * dimension) {
    video_height = video_width * dimension;
} else if ($(window).height() < 364){
    video_height = $(window).height() - $('text_cont').height();
    video_width = (video_height / dimension);
}
```